# how to append the specific values in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

This is my directive.I want to append the array specific array value in existing array

localStorage.getItem('albumcomments') = "[{"id":1,"photocomment":"sdfsdfs"}]";

```
angular.module('albumlikeFeature',[]).directive('albumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.likeCount = 0;
        scope.unlikeCount = 0;


        scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {
        scope.likeCount += 1;          

        if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments'))){

                var newDataLike = [];
                 angular.forEach(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments'), function(likeCount, item){
                    console.log('test');
                    newDataLike.push({id:item.id, photocomment:item.photocomment, like:likeCount});
                });

                console.log(newDataLike);
                localStorage.setItem('albumcomments',JSON.stringify(newDataLike));

        }

      };
```

My expected output is

```
[{"id":1,"photocomment":"test","like":"1","unlike":"1"}
```

Now output is

```
[{"like":"["},{"like":"{"},{"like":"\""},{"like":"i"},{"like":"d"},{"like":"\""},{"like":":"},{"like":"1"},{"like":","},{"like":"\""},{"like":"p"},{"like":"h"},{"like":"o"},{"like":"t"},{"like":"o"},{"like":"c"},{"like":"o"},{"like":"m"},{"like":"m"},{"like":"e"},{"like":"n"},{"like":"t"},{"like":"\""},{"like":":"},{"like":"\""},{"like":"s"},{"like":"d"},{"like":"f"},{"like":"s"},{"like":"d"},{"like":"f"},{"like":"s"},{"like":"\""},{"like":"}"},{"like":"]"}]
```

Comment: Iterate over the array and mutate the objects accordingly? You don't have to push anything to the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope it will help

```
    angular.module('albumlikeFeature',[]).directive('albumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.likeCount = 0;
      scope.unlikeCount = 0;
      
      
            scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {
      scope.likeCount += 1;          
      
      if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments'))){
        
        var newDataLike = [];
         angular.forEach(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments')), function(likeCount, item){    
         newDataLike.push({id:likeCount.id, photocomment:likeCount.photocomment, like:scope.likeCount,unlike:scope.unlikeCount});
        });
        
        localStorage.setItem('albumcomments',JSON.stringify(newDataLike));
      }
      
          };
       
        scope.unlikeClick = function (dataid) {
        scope.unlikeCount += 1;          
      
      if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments'))){
        
        var newDataUnlike = [];
         angular.forEach(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments')), function(i, item){
         newDataUnlike.push({id:i.id, photocomment:i.photocomment,like:scope.likeCount,unlike:scope.unlikeCount});
        });

        console.log(newDataUnlike);
        localStorage.setItem('albumcomments',JSON.stringify(newDataUnlike));
      }
      
          };
       
        }           
     }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.getItem('albumcomments') = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"photocomment":"sdfsdfs"}]');

angular.module('albumlikeFeature',[]).directive('albumlikeFeature', ['$filter', '$route', function ($filter, $route) {

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: 'app/components/album/albumlikefeature.html',
  link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

  scope.likeCount = 0;
  scope.unlikeCount = 0;


  scope.likeClick = function (dataid) {
  scope.likeCount += 1;          

  if(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments').length > 0){

    var newDataLike = [];

    $.each(localStorage.getItem('albumcomments'), function(value, key){
      $(this) = $this;

      console.log('test');

      newDataLike.push( {id: $this.id, photocomment: $this.photocomment, like: scope.likeCount} );
    });

    console.log(newDataLike);
    localStorage.setItem('albumcomments',JSON.stringify(newDataLike));

  }

};
```

Try that

Comment: Better. Any reason why can't write "you" instead of "u"? This is not Twitter, there isn't really a character limit.

Comment: Actually, it's wrong. Why are passing the object to jquery?

Comment: @user2598136 if u do not want use jQuery - i re-write to pure js (but in my exp - jQuery rly easier)

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant that `$(this)` is wrong. If you run the code you will notice that the original array does not change, since you are only mutating the jQuery object.

Comment: im most ruby and scala developer, sometimes i confuse at js closure and etc ) ty again @FelixKling

Comment: localStorage.getItem('albumcomments') = JSON.parse("[{"id":1,"photocomment":"sdfsdfs"}]"); @user2598136 try that way

Comment: im getting like this - `[{"like":{"id":1,"photocomment":"sdcfsfsdf"}}]`

Comment: yes, because you use code from Jai ans. i try to rewrite now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74482/discussion-between-legendary-and-user2598136).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create a new array and then you can push the things while iterating:

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"photocomment":"test"},{"id":1,"photocomment":"test1"}];
var newData = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    newData.push({id:item.id, photocomment:item.photocomment, like:i, unlike:i});
});

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: interesting, but what dont modify old array[Object] ?

Comment: It that case it would be a tiny bit more elegant to use `.map`.

Comment: its running mutiple times @jai now my output is `[{"like":"["},{"like":"{"},{"like":"\""},{"like":"i"},{"like":"d"},{"like":"\""},{"like":":"},{"like":"1"},{"like":","},{"like":"\""},{"like":"p"},{"like":"h"},{"like":"o"},{"like":"t"},{"like":"o"},{"like":"c"},{"like":"o"}]`

Comment: how can i fix this  ?